# How can exempt a domain from an OpenVPN connection?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN connection open at all times which results in certain services like Pandora to not work since the OpenVPN connection goes to Europe. How can I exempt a domain, in this case pandora.com, from the OpenVPN connection?